# Font Awesome in Javascript Error: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier ​

Tags: javascript, font-awesome

I just discovered a font library named Font Awesome. I tried to integrate it as followed but I got the error message in the console. 
" Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier "

```js
var button= document.getElementById("btn");
var icon=document.getElementById("ic");

button.addEventListener("click", function(){
 icon.innerHTML="<i class="fa fa-wifi" aria-hidden="true"></i>";
}
```

```html
<head>
 <script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/180fe96fd3.js"></script>
</head>



<body>
<button id="btn">Click for wifi</button>
<p>
<span id="ic"></span>
</p>
</body>
```

Basically, what I want to do is, when the user click the icons, the wifi icons from font awesome appeared in the span area. Am I using the correct method for usage in Javascript? Once again, thank you for your time.

Comment: `"<i class=\"fa fa-wifi\" aria-hidden=\"true\"></i>";` or `"<i class='fa fa-wifi' aria-hidden='true'></i>";`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have write `<i>` with `""` string and inside string use `""`

so thats why error generated

use like below two way

```
 icon.innerHTML='<i class="fa fa-wifi" aria-hidden="true"></i>';
```

or

```
icon.innerHTML="<i class='fa fa-wifi' aria-hidden='true'></i>";
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a problem with text escaping. Try `icon.innerHTML='<i class="fa fa-wifi" aria-hidden="true"></i>';`. Notice the use of single quotes.